# Aplicação do facebook compartilha o link mas não mostra no feed

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

Criei uma App para compartilhar um link usando o método *feed*.
Funcionou tudo direitinho mas o link compartilhado só aparece na minha timeline, não aparece no feed de notícias, ou seja, somente eu o posso ver.

> Obs: tive o cuidado de tornar o **acesso público** na *dialog* mas não adiantou.

Alguém saberia me dizer o que houve de errado?
O código que usei é o básico mesmo:

```
FB.UI({ 
  method: 'feed', 
  link: 'http://www.meusite.com',
  picture: 'http://www.meusite.com/images/minhaimagem.jpg',
  name: 'Compartilhando',
  caption: 'Meu texto',
  description: 'Minha descrição.'
});
```

Comment: Eu não tenho 100% certeza, mas penso que é suposto ele comportar-se mesmo dessa maneira. Já o botão `compartilhar` normal, pode tornar as publicações visíveis no feed de notícias/homepage. Podes levantar esta questão no grupo [Facebook Developers Community](https://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/?ref=browser) para uma resposta mais precisa e detalhada pela equipa do Facebook.

Comment: Obrigado Chun foi procurar me informar

Comment: Mudei para share mas ficou como antes :(

Comment: Eu usei as permissões básicas, não mandei o app para revisão. Seria este o motivo?